# Class variable not returned correctly

Tags: php

```
class userDetails {
    private $usersEmail;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    // check if it's returned
    // echo $usersEmail.' '.$firstName.' '.$lastName;
    //setter for class properties
    public function __constructor($email,$fname,$lname) {

        $this->usersEmail = $email;
        $this->firstName = $fname;
        $this->lastName = $lname;       
    }

    //getter for class properties
    function getPropertyEmail() {
        return $this->usersEmail;
    }
    function getPropertyFName() {
        return ($this->firstName);      
    }
    function getPropertyLName() {
        return ($this->lastName);       
    }
}
$something = "something";
 //$something is actually a $_GET['id']; sent from xhrobject 
$createdUser = new userDetails($something,$something,$something);
echo $createdUser->getPropertyEmail();
```

Comment: Elaborate on the issue that you are having - it is not at all clear what you are having trouble with. Please don't just post your (horribly formatted) code in the question and then not explain it.

Comment: I'm creating a class which includes 3 properties. Constructor gets initial values from an xhrObject. Then I'm using getMethods to return each property of class userDetails. Now when I echo or print_r on not getters, php doesn't prints a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Please use __construct()  method instead __constructor()

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
class userDetails {
    private $usersEmail;
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;

    // check if it's returned
    // echo $usersEmail.' '.$firstName.' '.$lastName;
    //setter for class properties
    public function __construct($email,$fname,$lname) {

        $this->usersEmail = $email;
        $this->firstName = $fname;
        $this->lastName = $lname;       
    }

    //getter for class properties
    function getPropertyEmail() {
        return $this->usersEmail;
    }
    function getPropertyFName() {
        return ($this->firstName);      
    }
    function getPropertyLName() {
        return ($this->lastName);       
    }
}
$something = "something";
 //$something is actually a $_GET['id']; sent from xhrobject 
$createdUser = new userDetails($something,$something,$something);
echo $createdUser->getPropertyEmail();
```